# How to disable requiretty for a single command in sudoers?

Tags: sudo

I want to disable requiretty so that I can sudo within scripts, but I'd rather only disable it for a single command rather than everything. Is that possible within the sudoers config?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can override the default setting for options such as `requiretty` for a specific user or for a specific command (or for a specific run-as-user or host), but not for a specific command when executed as a specific user.

For example, assuming that `requiretty` is set in the compile-default options, the following `sudoers` file allows both `artbristol` and `bob` to execute `/path/to/program` as root from a script. `artbristol` needs no password whereas `bob` must have to enter a password (presumably `tty_tickets` is off and `bob` entered his password on some terminal recently).

```
artbristol ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/program
bob ALL = (root) /path/to/program
Defaults!/path/to/program !requiretty
```

If you want to change the setting for a command with specific arguments, you need to use a command alias (this is a syntax limitation). For example, the following fragment allows `artbristol` to run `/path/to/program --option` in a script, but not `/path/to/program` with other arguments.

```
Cmnd_Alias MYPROGRAM = /path/to/program --option  
artbristol ALL = (root) /path/to/program
artbristol ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: MYPROGRAM
Defaults!MYPROGRAM !requiretty
```

Comment: The one with the argument might need a wildcard in the end as well(?): `If a Cmnd has associated command line arguments, then the arguments in the Cmnd must match exactly those given by the user on the command line (or match the wildcards if there are any).`

Comment: @aderchox The point of my example was to show how to allow _only_ a specific argument list.

Answer (score 35):

Something like this:

```
myuser    ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD:/usr/local/bin/mycmd
Defaults:myuser        !requiretty
```

Comment: This might work in `/etc/sudoers` but does not appear to work in a `/etc/sudoers.d/` file

Comment: For what it's worth, for me, this edit did work when added to a `/etc/sudoers.d/` file. CentOS 7.1

Comment: It doesn't work for me when using `/etc/sudoers.d/`. CentOS 7.5 :(

Answer (score 4):

I found it works fine for me using a file in `/etc/sudoers.d`.  It is quite simple to verify.

First, I created `/etc/sudoers.d/01build` with the contents:

```
build    ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD:/bin/date
Defaults:build !requiretty
```

Then tested that it works:

```
ssh host sudo -n /bin/date
Mon Nov 16 16:04:27 CST 2015
```

Then I modified `/etc/sudoers.d/01build` and deleted the `Defaults:` line, and after that, I get:

```
ssh host sudo -n /bin/date
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```