# sudo hangs when run on remote host over ssh in a script without tty (-t)

Tags: bash, ssh, sudo, aix

I have an AIX 6.1 server where I need to run a remote `sudo` command in a bash script.

Here is my bash script simplified:

**testSudo.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
set -x

sudo env
```

I can run the `sudo` command locally without password:

```
[user@server]$ sudo env
VAR=VAL
...
```

I can run the script locally:

```
[user@server]$ /tmp/testSudo.sh
+ sudo env
VAR=VAL
...
```

I can run `sudo` on the remote host:

```
[user@client]$ ssh user@server sudo env
VAR=VAL
...
```

I can run the script on the remote host with tty:

```
[user@client]$ ssh -t user@server /tmp/testSudo.sh
+ sudo env
VAR=VAL
...
```

I can't run the script on the remote host without tty (and I can't add the -t option in my context):

```
[user@client]$ ssh user@server /tmp/testSudo.sh
+ sudo env
```

It hangs there.

Comment: Does running sudo on the remote server require a password?

Comment: So why not run `ssh -t`?

Comment: @jw013 No there is no password required while runnig sudo on the remote server.

Comment: @Gilles I'm making the request, is an extarnal program who does, so I can't change the ssh options.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/79960/117549

Answer (score 1):

Sudo when executed w/o terminal requires a helper program to handle password query:

```
SUDO_ASKPASS    Specifies the path to a helper program used to read the
password if no terminal is available or if the -A option is specified.
```

Normally when you connect via ssh and sudo will need a password but terminal is not allocated it will blow an error - on AIX this can behave different.

Check your sudo settings and enable NOPASSWD from all remote machines also, correct rule should look like that (add it on the end of /etc/sudoers) :

`user  ALL= NOPASSWD:/tmp/testSudo.sh`

Comment: I don't understand why I need to add 'user ALL= NOPASSWD:/tmp/testSudo.sh' in my sudoers. This script is not played in a sudo but it plays a sudo : 'sudo env'. I allready have a line saying  'user ALL= NOPASSWD:env'.

Comment: 8 mnths delay in answer - hope you accept that ;) I would make a try and use fullpath to env ( like '/usr/bin/env' ) both in sudo config and your script.