# ERROR: no tty present and no askpass program specified ; TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ;

Tags: sudo

In my /etc/sudoers.d/myAppCommand file I set some command like this.

```
Cmnd_Alias APP_CMD = /opt/myApp/lib/app-start, \
                                    /opt/myApp/lib/app-stop, \
                                    /opt/myApp/lib/app-restart
#Rules section
#
my-app ALL = NOPASSWD: APP_CMD
```

But at the time of installation this command giving the below error:

```
2015-01-12 08:22:27 SecurityEvent sudo Rack1 alert sudo:  my-app : no tty present and no askpass program specified ; TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/opt/myApp/lib/app-start
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason you have `requiretty` set in your `sudoers` file. Since it's disabled by default it was set either by your distro, administrator, or you.

See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/79960) for how to disable `requiretty` for a single command.