# How can I obtain a shell without pty

Tags: bash, tty

I'm in the process of fixing a script which fails because it invokes `sudo` in an environment without a pty which has a sudoers file defining `Default requiretty`.

The script is executed by `root` and uses `sudo` to call binaries which depend on being executed by specific users, so my solution was to replace those `sudo` by `su`.

Now I want to test my modifications, but I have a hard time reproducing the environment where `sudo` failed :

- I can access the machine through another user, then log as root with `sudo su -`. I don't know `root`'s password.
- I know how to access the machine without a pty with `ssh -T`, but then I can't log as root anymore because `sudo` fails.

How could I get a root shell without pty ?

Comment: Just for testing, can you edit your sudoers file so that one of your users can run sudo su without entering a password, using the NOPASSWD directive? If you do this and then ssh -T, you may be able to use sudo su to become root without getting a PTY.

Comment: It is possible to make exceptions from default requiretty, if you are allowed to do so. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79960/how-to-disable-requiretty-for-a-single-command-in-sudoers

Comment: I would have preferred avoiding to edit any configuration on the machine but I guess removing the requiretty constraint on `sudo su -` or making it  `NOPASSWD` should do the trick. I will try this out.

Comment: Are you on a Redhat system? They used to ship sudoers with default requiretty, but recently changed that:  https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1196451. Maybe that helps you in deciding.

Comment: Yes, that's a RHEL 6.6. The problem is that the script is executed on a wide array of machines including a good amount of such installs, and I can't expect every machine to change its sudoers conf. Thanks for the bug report anyway, in particular because it points out that NOPASSWD won't work

Comment: Related: [Why do I need a tty to run sudo if I can sudo without a password?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/122616)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing I'd try is to execute your script with `at` or `cron`.

Example:

```
at now <<< "sudo echo 'This will fail if sudoers requiretty' 2>/tmp/stderr >/tmp/stdout"
```