# SUDO requiring tty

Tags: sudo, amazon-linux

On Amazon Linux 2018.03, I have a process running as an unprivileged user and calls sudo to run a command.  I'm getting the message:

```
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

The unprivileged user (xymon) is allowed to run the command in question without password

```
Cmnd_Alias YUM = /usr/bin/yum
xymon   ALL=(ALL)               NOPASSWD: YUM
```

The command is being called from a perl script executed by the local xymon client process via the following lines:

```
my $YumCmd  = 'sudo yum check-update  2>&1' ;
@Lines = `$YumCmd` ;
```

In /etc/sudoers, I have supposedly disabled the tty requirement with:

```
Defaults    !requiretty
```

No luck. None of the includes set requiretty.

sudo -ll as the xymon user is below:

```
Matching Defaults entries for xymon on this host:
!visiblepw, always_set_home, env_reset, env_keep="COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS", env_keep+="MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE",
env_keep+="LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES", env_keep+="LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE", env_keep+="LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS
_XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY", !requiretty, secure_path=/sbin\:/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin, requiretty, !visiblepw, env_reset, env_keep="COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR
LS_COLORS", env_keep+="MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE", env_keep+="LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES", env_keep+="LC_MONETARY LC_NAME
LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE", env_keep+="LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY", !authenticate

User xymon may run the following commands on this host:

Sudoers entry:
RunAsUsers: ALL
Commands:
    NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/yum
```

I notice that `requiretty` does appear in the output but does not appear to be overridden by my `Defaults !requiretty` directive.  Placing the `Defaults !requiretty` directive at the very end of the sudoers file places it just before the `requiretty` listed in `sudo -ll`.  No idea where this is coming from.

Using a pseudo-tty with ssh does work using the following command:

```
my $YumCmd  = 'ssh -tt -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa localhost sudo yum check-update  2>&1' ;
```

This is not a good option given the large amount of setup needed for the many servers to run this script (Xymon script).  Any suggestions for getting this to work with sudo or is this a bug?

Comment: check the answer of this Q. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79960/how-to-disable-requiretty-for-a-single-command-in-sudoers

Comment: I've updated my question to answer the query from @dsstorefile1

Comment: @Michael D. - I had previously read the Q. that you recommended and tried all of those things.  No luck.

Comment: Can you `su xymon` and check the output of `sudo -ll` ?

Comment: @Michael D.  The sudo-ll output has been added to the Q.  !requiretty shows up.  Odd.

Comment: @roaima - I updated the Q. to show how it is being called.

Comment: @roaima - apologies for not including that info.  The Q. is updated.  The script is called by the local xymon client process.

Comment: I see both `!requiretty` and `requiretty` in your `sudo -ll` output. Later rules usually win. Can you track down where the second one is coming by from?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick excellent catch. I'd looked but missed the second instance.

Comment: Does `/etc/sudoers.d/` directory exist? If it exists, are there any files in it that contain more `Defaults` settings?

Comment: `/etc/sudoers.d/` does exist, but no files there have Defaults settings.  I'm thinking that the requiretty must be baked into this distro of sudo.

Answer (score 2):

Issue solved.  I had included `requiretty` in my LDAP.

`cn=defaults,OU=SUDOers` sudoOption `requiretty` changed to `!requiretty` and all works properly.

I will now limit `!requiretty` to just the affected user.