# List IP tables in Docker Container

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, iptables, docker

I want to run the `iptables` command in a Ubuntu 16.04 Docker container.  I have created a user, given that user root permissions, added them to the `sudo` group, but I am still being told that I am not running `iptables` as root.

```
$ groups
stack root sudo

$ sudo whoami
root

$ sudo iptables --list
iptables v1.6.0: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Permission 
denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

In my `/etc/sudoers` file I have the line: `%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`, which I believe should allow any user in the `sudo` group (which I am) to run any command, but I still get the permission denied error.

How would I successfully run the `iptables` command as this user?

Please note I am doing this in a Docker container with image: `ubuntu:16.04`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

#### Capabilities

If you want have `iptables` access within your containers, you need to enable specific capabilities via the `--cap-add=NET_ADMIN` switch when running the container initially.

#### Example

```
$ docker run --cap-add=NET_ADMIN -it ubuntu:16.04
```

Then in the container set up `iptables` & `sudo`:

```
# apt update -y
# apt-get install iptables sudo -y
```

Then inside the container, set up a user, `user1`, and added it to the `sudo` group:

```
# adduser user1
# adduser user1 sudo
```

Then set user to `user1`:

```
# su - user1
```

Check `user1'`s sudo permissions:

```
$ sudo -l
[sudo] password for user1:
Matching Defaults entries for user1 on 1356bf8bd61a:
    env_reset, mail_badpass, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/snap/bin

User user1 may run the following commands on 1356bf8bd61a:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
```

Check if they can access `iptables` via `sudo`:

```
$ sudo iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

#### References

- [How to start “ubuntu” docker container](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-start-ubuntu-docker-container/30107)
- [Docker run reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#general-form)
- [How can I add a new user as sudoer using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7477/how-can-i-add-a-new-user-as-sudoer-using-the-command-line)
- [How to disable requiretty for a single command in sudoers?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79960/how-to-disable-requiretty-for-a-single-command-in-sudoers)

Comment: That worked!  Thanks for the detailed answer! Alternatively, I also found that using the `--privileged` flag works as well

Comment: @northsideknight - that gives all capabilities to the container whereas what I show just gives the networking, so is a little more secure. It's discussed here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36425230/privileged-containers-and-capabilities.

Comment: ah yes, good point

Comment: How would you do it in Compose 3 ? The doc says the cap_add: option is ignored https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

Comment: The `cap_add` and `cap_drop` options are ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode